# How can I set a shorthand alias for a variable?

Tags: powershell

I am using a script that sets `$Global:LastResult`, how can I set an alias, say, `last` to access this variable

Comment: This appears to be a case of 'xy problem' https://xyproblem.info/, or https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't define an alias for a variable (well, technically you can, as long as the variable isn't `$null`, but then your alias would have the value of the variable at the time of the assignment).

What you can do is define a function that returns the value of `$global:LastResult` and then an alias for that function:

```
function Get-LastResult { $global:LastResult }
New-Alias -Name last -Value Get-LastResult
```

However, I fail to see the advantage of an approach like this over directly using the variable `$global:LastResult`.

Comment: An advantage is that it is faster to type. (It can also be easier to memorize)

Comment: Tab-completion exists.

Comment: Even better, you can just use `$LastResult` in any scope where the $Global variable is not overridden.

This is not called an alias, and there's where everyone is chasing an XY problem.

If you've set a global variable, you merely have to call it correctly.

Also, if this is the output of a function, it's better to create a custom object and return that object, assigned to a variable in the appropriate scope.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the value of a global variable, you merely have to call the variable.

```
    PS c:> $Global:LastResult = 'foo'
    PS c:> $LastResult
    foo
```

If you want to return an array or multiple answers, build a custom object and return it as the result of your function/cmdlet.

```
$LastResult = MyCustomCmdlet($Input)

$LastResult

<whatever custom object>
```

In Powershell, aliases are short names for cmdlets or functions.  For a large number of examples, try:

```
Get-Alias
```

Or for just one, try:

```
Get-Alias gci
```

Answer (score -1):

You can:

```
Function CD32 {Set-Location -Path C:\Windows\System32}
Set-Alias -Name Go -Value CD32
```

[Create an alias for a command with parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-alias?view=powershell-7.3#example-5-create-an-alias-for-a-command-with-parameters)

Comment: They've already written a function that assigns a global variable and they want "to access this variable".  Your answer doesn't differ much from @ansgar_wiechers answer.

Comment: This doesn't address the actual question.